# How to set a Port Range for a LoadBalancer in Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, port, load-balancing, rancher

I'd need to set a port range for a workload as the running service has a dynamic port range - therefore I'd like to define the port range in the corresponding LoadBalancer in Rancher. Single Ports can be easily defined - but how would it work with a port range?

I've simply tried "32768-60999" (see yellow marked row), but after that the "Save" button gets disabled.

[image]

Curious about that...
Thx!

Comment: If you set a NodePort without giving it a value, Rancher chooses a port at random from the following range: 30000-32767. But we cannot give a specific range, so try to give one value or leave it blank so that the rancher will select from the available range.

Comment: So, the answer of the whole question whether it is possbile to define a port range is simply no?

Comment: No, node port has a range of 30000-32767 we cannot set value beyond this predefined range, you can set one value between the range, if you want any random value then leave the nodeport as blank value so the rancher will select from the available range, please refer to this official [Rancher](https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/v2.0-v2.4/how-to-guides/new-user-guides/migrate-from-v1.6-v2.x/expose-services#nodeport) document for nodeport range.